# pusher-fake specs not able get the triggers sent from a delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, delayed-job, pusher

I have job running in background which triggers the pusher events frequently to the home page of the application to show the status of the process running.

When testing the process using rspec and pusher-fake, I see that the triggers are working for test which are directly coming from normal controller methods. But the triggers coming from background job are not observed by the pusher-fake specs.

I exactly followed the way pusher-fake example's specs are written https://github.com/tristandunn/pusher-fake-example.

Let me know how this problem can be resolved.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to post at least the error or part of your code for any one to help you to find the issue.

Comment: After checking the rspec logs I see that after running all the processes in job, then the page redirects to the page mentioned in controller. So that can be a reason for the listener not getting the trigger, which is already sent long back.